# quick sort list of tuple with python

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to do this in its operation algorithm quicksort to sort though the elements of a list of tuples. Or if I have a list of this type [(0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,3), (4,2), (5,1), (6,4 )] I want to sort it in function of the second element of each tuple and obtain [(6,4), (3,3), (4,2), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1 ), (5,1)]. I have tried using the following algorithm:

```
def partition(array, begin, end, cmp):
pivot=array[end][1]
ii=begin
for jj in xrange(begin, end):
  if cmp(array[jj][1], pivot):
    array[ii], array[jj] = array[jj], array[ii]
    ii+=1
array[ii], array[end] = pivot, array[ii]
return ii

enter code hedef sort(array, cmp=lambda x, y: x > y, begin=0, end=None):
if end is None: end = len(array)
if begin < end:
    i = partition(array, begin, end-1, cmp)
    sort(array, cmp, i+1, end)
    sort(array, cmp, begin, i)
```

The problem is that the result is this: [4, (3, 3), (4, 2), 1, 1, 1, (5, 1)]. What do I have to change to get the correct result ??

Comment: Is there something wrong with `list.sort`?

Comment: Specifically: `sorted([(0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,3), (4,2), (5,1), (6,4 )], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`.

Comment: @wkschwartz not familiar enough with python but list.sort take O(n^2) i guess

Comment: Python's [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is state of the art. It has worst case time complexity of O(nlogn).

Comment: please fix your indentation

Answer (score 2):

Complex sorting patterns in Python are painless. Python's [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is state of the art, one of the fastest available in real-world cases. No algorithm design needed.

```py
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [(0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,3), (4,2), (5,1), (6,4 )]
>>> l.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
>>> l
[(6, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (5, 1)]
```

Above, [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) returns a function that returns the second element of its argument. Thus the `key` argument to `sort` is a function that returns the item on which to sort the list.

Python's sort is stable, so the ordering of elements with equal keys (in this case, the second item of each tuple) is determined by the original order.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer from @wkschwartz only works due to the peculiar start ordering of the terms. If the tuple (5, 1) is moved to the beginning of the list then it gives a different answer.

The following (first) method works in that it gives the same result for any initial ordering of the items in the initial list.

```
Python 3.4.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Oct 22 2014, 11:51:45) [MSC v
.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> l = [(0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,3), (4,2), (5,1), (6,4 )]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
[(6, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (5, 1)]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[(6, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (5, 1)]
>>> # but note:
>>> l2 = [(5,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,3), (4,2), (0,1), (6,4 )]
>>> # Swapped first and sixth elements
>>> sorted(l2, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[(6, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 1)]
>>> sorted(l2, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
[(6, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (5, 1)]
>>>
```

Comment: Good point. It's because Python sorts are stable. Edited my answer to reflect this.